# Maven failsafe doesn't read environmentVariables config for integration tests

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

My Maven build comprises of unit and integrations test executions as 2 separate profiles with Jacoco for code-coverage.
I am having couple of problems with **failsafe** plugin and require a direction to look for resolutions. I've already snailed through numerous content available but couldn't resolve the problem yet.

1. `<environmentVariables>` do not work for failsafe, while it does for surefire . I've tried everything from `<systemProperties>`,`<systenPropertiesVariables>`,`<properties>`; but none seem to work to set environment variables for my Integrations test cases.
2. <s>Test case exclusions using `<excludes>` is not working for failsafe; where as it does for surefire.</s>

My failsafe configuration is:

```
<profile>
    <id>it-coverage</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- MAVEN Failsafe plugin. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <config>config/preferences.xml</config>
                        <log4jproperties>config/log4j.properties</log4jproperties>
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/it-jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                    </environmentVariables>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*UTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes> 
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*ITest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: point 2 is resolved now. I added Surefire-plugin in my failsafe profile and marked <skip>true</skip>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my problems are resolved.
I added **surefire-plugin** to my integration profile along with **failsafe-plugin** and everything started falling in place.

Below is the configuration which worked for me.

```
<profile>
    <id>it-coverage</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- MAVEN Failsafe plugin. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                    <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <config>${config.preferences}</config>
                        <log4jproperties>${config.log4jproperties}</log4jproperties>
                        <!-- <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/it-jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile> -->
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*ITest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- MAVEN Jacoco plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*UTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution> 
                        <id>default-instrument</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer how to get failsafe to read environment variables though, right? You just ended up using system properties instead. It looks like one can pass system properties in via the <systemPropertyVariables> element or the <argLine> element but environment variables aren't read/used.

Comment: About "systemPropertyVariables" https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/system-properties.html