# How to configure environment variables maven-failsafe-plugin

Tags: java, maven

In a legacy Java project, `maven-surefire-plugin` was used for *integration test* and, inside the `maven-surefire-plugin` element in `pom.xml` there is the following `executions`:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
            </includes>
            <environmentVariables>
                <mavenRun>true</mavenRun>
            </environmentVariables>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

In this legacy part of code, `environmentVariables` is used. As a result,

> **QUESTION**: after replacing `maven-surefire-plugin` with `maven-failsafe-plugin` by keeping all other parts unchanged, the
> `environmentVariables` cannot be recognized. So **How to configure
> environment variables in the `maven-failsafe-plugin`?**

Comment: I'm not so sure what type of env vars you want to pass, there is a question related to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898854/maven-failsafe-doesnt-read-environmentvariables-config-for-integration-tests

Comment: @SergheiMotpan Thanks first for the link. I checked that link and one comment told that the given answer did not answer the question relevant to the environment variable and I also think so

Comment: Can you provide/elaborate an example what variable/flag you want maven-failsafe to handle?